# Permanently casting a variable in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, casting

I needed some help with casting in SQL Server.

Usually, there are occassions when I need to cast a variable, and normally I do it while doing a join. Below is just an example.

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE1 a
INNER JOIN TABLE2 b ON b.SomeID = CAST(SomeID AS xx)
```

My question is, instead of doing lots of casting to the variable that will be used a lot, how can I permanently cast it to a specific datatype?

Let's say I need to cast it permanently from `float` to `int`

Comment: What is `SomeID` here? If it's a variable, as you say, then what is the relationship between `TABLE1` and `TABLE2`? I'm not entirely sure what happens if you join on a fixed value (`ON b.SomeID = 2`), but I doubt it does what you'd want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declare another variable of the `xx` type and use that....

```
DECLARE @New_Var AS xx;

SET @New_Var = CAST( @SomeID AS  xx) 

SELECT
*
FROM TABLE1 a
INNER JOIN TABLE2 b

ON b.SomeID= @New_Var
```

Answer (score 1):

You can alter your table schema. However take into acount that some data might be lost if there is no valid cast from float to int:

```
alter table Table1 alter column ID int
```

Comment: That is an interesting solution as I am trying to use more and more UPDATE and ALTER statements. Could you explain a bit more why data might be lost if there is no valid CAST from float to int? wouldn't SQL SERVER stop that and prompt an error?

Comment: OP needs to cast a variable

Comment: I tried this solution and it did not work. It says "incorrect syntax  near 'someID'.

Comment: I got the above alter example code to work after adding COLUMN. Just a stupid question, if I needed to alter multiple columns, how would I do that?  Writing this does not work:alter table Table1 alter column xx AND YY  INT